# Programmatically adding a grid of buttons inside Relative layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

My intention is to programmatically create a grid of buttons inside a Relative Layout. The reason why I want to do it programmatically is because the number of buttons varies by situation, i.e. I might need 12 buttons instead of 9 and so on.

[I managed to do this but with a Linear layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTJUC.png)

[However, this is the desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzR1J.png)

As far as I can tell, I need to create the buttons inside a Relative Layout instead but [this is what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO22G.png) when I change the layout to Relative.. They just stack on top of each other.

Here is the code that creates the buttons:

```
for (int i = 0; i < frows; i++) {
        LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        row.setPadding(0, 40, 0, 0);

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            ContextThemeWrapper newContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(getBaseContext(), R.style.ExerciseButtonTheme);
            eBtn = new Button(newContext);
            eBtn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            eBtn.setText("" + (j + 1 + (i * 3)));
            eBtn.setId(j + 1 + (i * 3));

            eBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.exercisebutton);
            row.addView(eBtn);

            eBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListActivity.class);
                    id = "" + view.getId();
                    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, id);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        }

        layout.addView(row);
    }
```

I've spent a lot of time trying to figure it out and search for existing answers but to no avail. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

```
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#449def"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#2f6699"/>
        <corners android:radius="6dp"/>
        <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient android:startColor="#449def" android:endColor="#2f6699" android:angle="270"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#2f6699"/>
        <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
        <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.`findViewById` for `RelativeLayout`**

**2.add outer `LinearLayout`**

**3.add inner `LinearLayout` and add `Button`**

**4.add `Button` to the inner `LinearLayout`**

**5.add inner `LinearLayout` to the outer `LinearLayout`**

**6.add outer `LinearLayout` to the `RelativeLayout` .**

And I use in the `Activity` class  .And You can change when you use other class .
Try this .

```
private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_your);
    // findViewById for RelativeLayout
    mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_relative);
    // add LinearLayout
    LinearLayout linear = new LinearLayout(this);
    linear.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    // set setOrientation
    linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        row.setPadding(0, 40, 0, 0);

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            Button eBtn = new Button(this);
            eBtn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            eBtn.setText("" + (j + 1 + (i * 3)));
            eBtn.setId(j + 1 + (i * 3));

            eBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.exercisebutton);
            // add view to the inner LinearLayout
            row.addView(eBtn);

            eBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListActivity.class);
                    id = "" + view.getId();
                    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, id);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
        // add view to the outer LinearLayout
        linear.addView(row);
    }
    mRelativeLayout.addView(linear);
}
```

**Edit**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit**

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.setMargins(10,10,10,10);
yourBtn.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Comment: I tried that, but I still can't separate the buttons? Tried tweaking the style of the buttons but android:layout_marginLeft does nothing. I think its because the buttons are still inside a Linear layout so they are always going to be right next to each other? It looks exactly like the first picture that I linked in my original post. The rows are separated just fine but I can't separate each individual button from each other..

Comment: You should remove your code .And try again .You can see the `output` .

Comment: Could you show me the xml files as well? I must have done something wrong with the styles then because I copy pasted your code and it still did not work properly

Comment: Where do you style the buttons themselves?

Comment: You just do like `eBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.exercisebutton);` .`setTextColor` .

Comment: Where and how have you defined your button margins? Can't do it in R.drawable.exercisebutton

Comment: eBtn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));.And you can set `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` as a object .And do with it .

Comment: You can check it .And I think you should google for it first .

Answer (score 0):

I think u just need to add layout_margin in your button layout file (but using Linear Layout instead of Relative Layout), example:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/eBtn"/>
```